# Trouble installing wireless drivers

Tags: drivers, iwlwifi

I have this [wifi card](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Gigabyte_GC-WB867D-I-L_rev_4.2) that wasn't working with Ubuntu due to driver issues. I figured that this [Intel Wireless 8260 (4.1)](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi) driver would be the one to solve my problem but when I downloaded and tried to install it with dpkg I got the following error:

```
Preparing to unpack firmware-iwlwifi_20161130-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking firmware-iwlwifi (20161130-3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive firmware-iwlwifi_20161130-3_all.deb (--install):
trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-11-5.ddc', which is also in package linux-firmware 1.157
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

Attempts to install it with the GUI also didn't do anything. What am I missing/should I try to reolve the issue?